# Hash::check not returning appropriate result

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, hash

I have a `users` table which stores registered users' `username, email, password`. Passwords are hashed via `Hash::make()` function before being saved into their respective table records.

I'm attempting to manually create an `AuthController` module from scratch.

In my `authenticate()` function, I'm checking if the password entered by the user attempting to the login matches the hashed password corresponding to the username as follows:

```
public function authenticate(AuthRequest $request)
{
    $hashedPassword = User::where('name', $request->name)
        ->select('password')
        ->get();

    $auth = Hash::check($request->password, $hashedPassword);

    //Die dumping just to check if the hash check has worked
    dd($auth);
}
```

Here, `AuthRequest` is the Request class that validates the form input before passing the `$request` variable to the `authenticate()` function.

Now, unfortunately, the `Hash::check()` function isn't responding as expected. I am, as coded above, trying to verify whether the password entered by the user in the login form matches the hashed password in the database table. But despite entering the same password as the hashed password the `$auth` variable receives a `false` value.

Comment: not to familiar with Laravel but I would expect `get` to return an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` returns a collection. To get the value directly, use the `value` method:

```
$hashedPassword = User::where($request->only('name'))->value('password');
```

Read [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#retrieving-results), under the section title **Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table**.

---

**P.S.** If you're using an older version of Laravel, that method was called `pluck`.

Answer (score 2):

Change [`get`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get) to [`first`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_first) to return the first item not the collection

```
$user = User::where('name', $request->name)
    ->select('password')
    ->first();

$hashedPassword = $user->password;
```